# How do solve the Multi-commodity problem for CPLEX?

Tags: opl

I’m learning to coding cplex recently, and some mathematical symbols don’t know how to express them as code.

I want to ask if anyone has coded a multicommodity problem for .mod code.

Help

Answer (score 0):

See OPL example CPLEX_Studio201\opl\examples\opl\transp

The decision variable is

```
dvar float+ Trans[Products][Cities][Cities];
```

Comment: Thx, I see this, because I need solve the Multi-commodity problem, but I don't know how can I transfer the complex formulation . [link](https://www.grotto-networking.com/MultiCommodity1.html) //  like the third formulation. help.